# Sorting Decimals in mysql to 2 decimal places vs more decimal places

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to constantly sort a table by a field that has a decimal datatype. I have added an index but I am not too sure how effective that is.

Would it be better to store the decimal as an integer, as the precision is not too necessary? Alternatively, I can simply increase the percentage until the smallest percentages can be rounded to more than 1 percent, and then round them, store them as integers, and sort them.

Which is faster, in order, and by how much?
Storing it as integer, with 2 decimal places or with multiple decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it as integers....This would mean that you would have a smaller index for the overlapping numbers as the percentages would go upto 100% and that would mean that lookups would be faster. Decimals are like storing long intergers in binary form.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the index will make any difference with sorting.  The main purpose of an index is for retrieving rows faster and I suspect you are not seaching for particular values.

So, I would leave the column as a decimal field so that your program does not have the additional overhead of converting the value whenver you retrieve or store it.

Comment: So I dont need an index to speed up a sort.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not a MySql expert, so I'm not sure.  Best way to find out is to time it with and without the sort.